# How to prevent convertation of float to string when importing Dataframe to Google Sheets?

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, pygsheets

I'm trying to send pandas DataFrame to Google Sheets with pygsheets. All values have defined data type. For example when I convert dataframe to_excel, excel reads floats as floats. But when i "send" dataframe with set_dataframe to Google Sheets they are transform to string and even dates. 
How to avoid that?

Comment: any example values you have tried. or code to re produce ?